# Работа с dbf-файлами

Tags: кодировка, php

Проблема такая: есть файл .DBF. Я его открываю:

```
  $dbh = dbase_open("bnk.dbf",2);
  if(!$dbh) exit("Ошибка - невозможно открыть файл");

  $numrecords = dbase_numrecords($dbh);

  for($i = 0; $i < $numrecords; $i++)
  {
    $arr[] = dbase_get_record($dbh, $i);
  }
  echo "<pre>";

  print_r($arr);
  echo "<pre>";

  dbase_close($dbh);
```

Всё выводит, но слова, которые есть в массиве `$arr`, не выводятся корректно! С кодировкой проблемы! Кто знает, помогите!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBF файл может быть и в ANSI и в DOS кодировках. В программе которая работает с dbf файлом можно задать кодировку, от этого и стоит строить последующее решение задачи.

Если кодировку можно изменить, то неоюходимо поменять её на ту, что использует скрипт, наприрмер, cp1251 или utf-8.

Если её не возможно изменить в программме, то нужно узнать в какой кодировке файл и под него настраивать декодирование в нужную кодировку.

И в совсем клиническом случае, скрипт должен сам определить кодировку и произвести декодирование.

У вас какой случай из трёх описанных?

Comment: этот файл был в кодировки ASCII! Я думал он в DOS, много мучился, а потом полазил по нэту и вспомнил о такой функции:

    convert_cyr_string($arr[$i][$j],'d','w');

и всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще функция [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php), но она работает только со строками, а не масивами.